# Can we replace XOR with multiply-add?

Tags: c++, cuda, bit-manipulation, xor, fma

I'm working on a CUDA program where ALU is fully utilized (almost 100% compute throughput). The program does a lot of XOR operations, among others. Is it possible to offload the XOR to the floating-point engine? As far as I know, `IMAD` instructions are not executed in the ALU, but rather in the FPU. In other words, can we replace `a XOR b` with something like `a*c + b`  (where `c` is some magic constant) or even 2-3 `IMAD` (integer multiply-add) instructions?

UPDATE: in response to the comments, `a` and `b` are 32-bit integers.

Comment: I don't see how.  Addition and multiplication both cross between bits which xor does not.  Addition does reduce to xor when you ignore the carry, so you can use addition to xor a single bit, but then all the more significant bits are "polluted".

Comment: Here's a proof.  `c=0` obviously doesn't work since it ignores `a` completely.  `c=1` doesn't work because it reduces to addition.  If `c >= 2` then because of overflow, it will give the same result for `a = 0` as for `a = 0x80000000`, regardless of the value of `b`, and that is not good either.

Comment: XOR of what? If it's single-bit XOR, you can emulate that with FMA since `a xor b = a + b - 2 * a * b`. Doesn't work for multi-bit integers.

Comment: The workhorse for logical operations in modern GPUs is the `LOP3` instruction that can provide *any* logical function of three inputs. While this already makes for some impressive throughput for apps heavily dependent on logical operations, it also creates a hard problem of finding the optimal mapping of more complex logical expressions to a tree of `LOP3` instructions. In general, the CUDA compiler does an OK job of this, but I frequently find that better mappings requiring fewer total `LOP3` instructions can be found manually. Have you looked into that?